# CakePHP. There is a $ this-> loadModel but the file itself is not a model. How is it?

Tags: cakephp, model

There is a `$this->loadModel('Something')` and it works, but the file itself is not a model. Where did he loads and takes information about a "Something"?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to understand what the question is.

Comment: Let's start over:  What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's highly unlikely that without a model defined it works, you should try to explain what the problem is better, and probably post some code snippets so we can better understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

it does it automotically. it workds with associations also :-)